# Strange problem when generating pdf online

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

I have straange problem with jsPDF, when i test on local pc, i generate PDF good, but when i upload online and try to generate, it looks like slipped, like in the picture

[Here is the link to sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BFW3.jpg)

i have tried just create PDF from HTML, but lots of problems, then i decided to create image from html, then add it to jsPDF page, its 2 page ID card, then generate PDF, it works ok on local, and it work ok sometime online, but most of time it is not working, like in the picture.

```
var qrcode = new QRCode("qrBox", { text: "https://sis.paragonisc.edu.kh/verify?code="+studentId, width: 180, height: 180, colorDark : "#000000", colorLight : "#ffffff", correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H });
            var settings = { output: 'css', bgColor: '#FFFFFF', color: '#000000', barWidth: 5, barHeight: 100, moduleSize: 10, addQuietZone: true, showHRI: false, };
            $("#barCodeBox").barcode(studentId, 'code39', settings);
            var pdf = new jsPDF({ orientation: 'portrait', unit: 'pt', format: [759, 1200] });
            var imgData = ""; var imgData2 = "";

            html2canvas($("#printPage"), {
                  onrendered: function(canvas) {
                      imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                      pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', 0, 0, 759, 1200);
                      $('#printPage').hide();
                      $('#printPage2').show();
                      pdf.addPage();
                      html2canvas($("#printPage2"), {
                            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                                imgData2 = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                                pdf.addImage(imgData2, 'JPG', 0, 0, 759, 1200);
                                pdf.save(arr[1]+'-'+arr[0]+'-'+studentId+'.pdf');
                                $('#qrBox').empty();
                                $('#loading').hide();
                            }
                        });
                  }
              });
```

Comment: when you say it's sometimes working, do you mean, the card is wide enough to fill the space or is it centered and it's width does not change?

Comment: sometimes work:  card full with the frame, no blank spaces on left , top or bottom,  but most of the time it slips to right and bottom.